# PHP in_array() function always true

Tags: php, arrays

Fixed! - Thanks to Barmar who's comments nudged me in the right direction. For what it is worth, the revised code is below. I wrapped everything in the in_array conditional instead of it being inside the loop. Thanks for the help, I know I didn't supply much context.

```
    $skufirst = str_split($product_skucart);


        if(!in_array($skufirst[0], $wildcards))
        {

                if($product_skuall != "")
                {
                    $i=0;

                      foreach($product_skuall as $skuall)
                        {
                            if(strstr($product_skucart,$skuall))
                            {   
                                    $bprice=$base_amountall[$i];
                                    $aprice=$additional_chargeall[$i];
                            }
                            $i++;
                        }

                        array_push($wildcards, $skufirst[0]);
                }

                    $base_amt = $bprice;
                    $additional_charge = $aprice;    
       }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything by quick glance. Any chance you can throw together an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: the first line of your script implies that `$product_skuall` is a string, but then you use it as an array in the first `foreach`. Which is it?

Comment: @Barmar - I added the start code of the parent else conditional. hopefully that clarifies what $product_skuall is. If not I'll see about an SSCCE. Thanks

Comment: OK, it clarifies that `$product_skuall` is an array, so why are you comparing it with a string? And why are you looping through the entire `$product_skuall` array inside the `while` loop that's building it (did you leave out the closing brace of that loop?).

Comment: OK, yes I see your point. This code is straight from Virtuemart 1.X for Joomla. I've been trying to add some custom functionality to it. The only bit that is mine is the str_split and in_array conditional. Yes I did leave out the closing brace sorry, only because it's about 1000 lines down the page:D

Comment: What is a sample value of $product_skucart ?

Comment: @Barmar - apologies, while loop closing brace added.

Comment: @janenz00 - a sample would be something like 'A436574'

Comment: Are you using `str_split()` for anything other than to get the first character? It not, just use `$product_skucart[0]`. But why are you doing this inside the loop, since `$product_skucart` doesn't change? Are you sure you don't mean to get the first character of `$skuall`?

Comment: @Barmar - yes you are right, your comment about where I'm doing it (inside the loop) has me on the right track now. I'm just testing and will reply if it was fixed.

Comment: @Barmar - That did it, the location for my in_array conditional was definitely the problem. See revised code above. Thanks heaps!

Comment: You still haven't explained what the point of `if ($product_skuall != "")` is. Why are you comparing an array to a string?

Comment: I know that conditional doesn't make sense and therefore can't understand why the code inside it runs. I will take a look and see what the logic behind it is as it is not my code.

Comment: @Etrain - it's good that you have a solution to your problem :-) When posting solutions on this site, even when they're answers to your own questions, please post them as an answer in the box below and mark it as accepted rather than editing the question with the solution. This will make it easier for future visitors with a similar problem to find the question and get help from it.

Answer (score 0):

For each product you are always checking for the same condition:

```
$skufirst = str_split($product_skucart);
```

You never touch $product_skucart!